# Cannot set read-only property ReflectionObject

Tags: php, reflection

I'm having difficulty writing to class properties using the Reflection API. `$p->setValue($r, $value)` throws an exception saying that the property is read only, however, PHP (to my knowledge) has no read only class properties (only methods using `final`), so what's the crack here?

The problem code:

```
    public function apply($source, $target) {
        $r = new \ReflectionObject($target);
        foreach ($source as $key => $value) {
            // $this->entries[$key] maps to a valid property of $target. Confirmed working
            $p = $r->getProperty($this->entries[$key]);
            $p->setAccessible(true);
            $p->setValue($r, $value); // <--- problem here
        }
    }
```

The exception reads as follows:

```
Uncaught ReflectionException: Cannot set read-only property ReflectionObject::$name
```

An excerpt from the class being reflected (`$target` in the above snippet), this issue remains whether I set the properties to `public` or keep `private`

```
class Target {

    private $id;
    private $name;

}
```

Nothing special going on with this class, just a plain object with a default constructor.

Is there something in the docs that I've missed, or is this just PHP weirdness that I need to accept?

Using version 7.1, but note that I haven't worked with PHP for over a decade (thankfully), so I may not be aware of obvious developments.

Comment: Can you add an example of a `$target` instance?

Comment: It's the last code block. Literally the entirety of the class, no methods, no constructor (implied default constructor), just those fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the instance you want to set the property on as the first argument in the `setValue()` call.

Have a look at this example:

```
<?php

class A
{
    private $name = 'ABC';
}

$obj = new A();

$r = new ReflectionObject( $obj );
$prop = $r->getProperty( 'name' );
$prop->setAccessible( true );
$prop->setValue( $obj, 'DEF' );

var_dump( $obj );
```

https://3v4l.org/ZdK27

The output is:

```
object(A)#1 (1) { ["name":"A":private]=> string(3) "DEF" }
```

Currently you try to set the property of the `ReflectionObject` instance, that coincidentally has a property with the same name. But this is not allowed by the runtime as it probably would break the reflection setup.